# Crawling with nutch throws IOException

Tags: java, web-crawler, nutch, ioexception

I've been trying to crawl using nutch. I'm using their Java API with following configuration -

```
Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
configuration.set("plugin.folders", "data/plugins");
configuration.set("hadoop.tmp.dir","data/tmp");
configuration.set("db.ignore.external.links","false");
configuration.set("db.fetch.schedule.class","org.apache.nutch.crawl.DefaultFetchSchedule");
configuration.set("db.url.normalizers","false");
configuration.set("db.url.filters","false");
configuration.set("db.ignore.external.links.mode","byDomain");
configuration.set("db.fetch.retry.max","3");
configuration.set("db.ignore.external.exemptions.file","data/conf/db-ignore-external-exemptions.txt");
configuration.set("plugin.includes","urlnormalizer-(ajax|basic|host|pass|protocol|querystring|regex|slash)|nutch-extensionpoints");
configuration.set("plugin.auto-activation", "true");
configuration.set("fetcher.follow.outlinks.depth", "10");
configuration.set("fetcher.follow.outlinks.num.links", "100");
configuration.set("http.agent.name", "Nutch Crawler");
configuration.set("fetcher.max.crawl.delay", "15000");
configuration.set("http.timeout", String.valueOf(25000));
configuration.set("http.content.limit", String.valueOf(1024 * 1024 * 512));
```

My code is -

```
public void crawlWithNutch() throws Exception{

    CrawlerConfiguration crawlerConf = new CrawlerConfiguration();
    Path crawlDB = crawlerConf.crawlDB();
    Path urlDir = crawlerConf.urlDir();

    System.out.println("Injecting urls to web table");
    Injector injector = crawlerConf.injector();
    injector.inject(crawlDB, urlDir);

    Path segmentsDir = crawlerConf.segmentsDir();
    Generator generator = crawlerConf.generator();
    Fetcher fetcher = crawlerConf.fetcher();
    ParseSegment parseSegment = crawlerConf.parseSegment();
    CrawlDb crawlDb = crawlerConf.crawlDb();
    FileDumper dumper = crawlerConf.dumper();

    long segmentTime = new Date().getTime();

    boolean stop = false;

    int numberOfReduceTasks = 8;
    int numberOfPagesInrun = 100;
    int numberOfCores = 2;

    while(!stop) {

        System.out.println("Generator phase");
        Path[] paths = generator.generate(crawlDB, segmentsDir, numberOfReduceTasks, numberOfPagesInrun, segmentTime);
        if(paths!=null && paths.length>0) {

            for (Path path : paths) {
                System.out.println("Fetch: " + path);
                fetcher.fetch(path, numberOfCores);
                System.out.println("Parse: " + path);
                parseSegment.parse(path);
            }
            System.out.println("Update: " + paths);
            crawlDb.update(crawlDB, paths, true, true);

        } else {
            stop = true;
        }
    }

    dumper.dump(new java.io.File("data/crawl/dump"),
            new java.io.File("data/crawl/segments"),
            tokenize("json"), true, true, false);


}
```

Its throwing an exception in fetch phase. Exception is -

```
13:34:00.564 [LocalJobRunner Map Task Executor #0] DEBUG org.apache.nutch.util.ObjectCache - No object cache found for conf=Configuration: core-default.xml, core-site.xml, mapred-default.xml, mapred-site.xml, yarn-default.xml, yarn-site.xml, hdfs-default.xml, hdfs-site.xml, file:/home/ishan/IdeaProjects/crawler/data/tmp/mapred/local/localRunner/ishan/job_local1687861686_0004/job_local1687861686_0004.xml, instantiating a new object cache
13:34:00.570 [LocalJobRunner Map Task Executor #0] WARN org.apache.nutch.parse.ParsePluginsReader - Unable to parse [null].Reason is [java.net.MalformedURLException]
java.io.IOException: Job failed!
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.runJob(JobClient.java:836)
    at org.apache.nutch.fetcher.Fetcher.fetch(Fetcher.java:486)
    at au.com.sensis.WebCrawler.crawlWithNutch(WebCrawler.java:217)
    at au.com.sensis.WebCrawler.main(WebCrawler.java:46)
```

I've done everything I could. But still I'm not able to get it working. Any help will be appreciated. I think its fetching the url as "null" and hence, throwing this exception.

Comment: You should make sure that nutch-default.xml is added to your configuration (see the class NutchConfiguration). Looks like parsing the file parse-plugins.xml (defined by the property parse.plugin.file) fails. Although it's possible to crawl by calling Nutch's Java method directly, it's much easier to use the provided shell scripts (bin/nutch and bin/crawl).

Comment: I've added property - `("parse.plugin.file","data/conf/parse-plugins.xml")` but still no luck. I think its getting null as a url which its not able to fetch. I don't understand why. Is there any way I can check if generate phase worked correctly. There is a part file generated under crawl_segment directory.

Comment: Yes, its easier to do it with bin/nutch but its a part of my project which consists of other functions too. Its a part of that and it will be better if I call its functions through java.

Comment: Maybe try `NutchConfiguration.create()` instead of `new Configuration()` and make sure the Nutch `conf/` folder is part of the classpath.

Comment: Tried it. Not working.

Comment: Just to verify: how is the main() method called. As setting up the class path isn't trivial the recommended way is `bin/nutch au.com.sensis.WebCrawler`. In doubt, start with the default configuration with the minimum required customization (only set `http.agent.name`). And have a look at existing main() methods (eg. Fetcher.main()).